# Listbox and scrollviewer wpf

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

I want to display the list of songs in the listbox. 
Example.

Song count 20. initially the listbox has to show 10 
like

song1

< song2  >

song3
...

If we click the right arrow it has to show the next 10.

Is it possible to achieve this.

Geetha.

Answer (score 2):

just go through this document

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Paging.aspx